# App dies with “Sending signal. SIG: 9” while rotating

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm working on cross-platform Unity application. I tested apps both on Android and iOS about month ago and they rotated properly. But now Android app is not rotating. But iOS app still rotate perfectly.

When I rotate mobile device, I receive next message in **Android Monitor**:

```
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2658 SIG: 9
```

I tried to override Activity's `onConfigurationChanged()` like [there](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange), but it doesn't invoke while phone rotating, so it stops earlier.

I tested this behavior both on phone (Doogee X5 Max, API 23) and emulators (API 19, 22 and 23). Result is the same.

What it can be caused? Thanks for response.

Maybe there can be some bugs in recent versions of Android developing environment (I have Android Studio 2.3, Android SDK Tools 25.2.2, Unity 5.5.2f1), but I didn't find any info about similar bugs in Google.

Comment: What do you mean by "rotate app"? Rotate the mobile device/accelerometer? Rotate display with code?

Comment: @Programmer I mean rotating mobile device

Comment: @Programmer and also Unity's `OnRectTransformDimensionsChange()` is not invoking, so app stops earlier

Comment: have you tried debugging it? like catching this exception in debugger to find a callstack?

Comment: @marcinj I tried like [there](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange), but Activity's `onConfigurationChanged()` doesn't invoke while phone rotating, so it stops earlier

Comment: What's your Android make and model number?

Comment: @Programmer I tried both on phone (Doogee X5 Max, API 23) and emulators (API 19, 22 and 23). Result is the same.

Comment: @Programmer What do you mean under plugins? I didn't install any additional software than pure Unity and Android Studio and all soft they installed for their work.

Comment: @Programmer No, I'm not using any plugins at all.

Comment: @Programmer Tried on API 17. Still crashing on rotating.

Comment: @Programmer Oh, sorry, version of Unity is 5.5.2f1 (the latest), just mistyped.

Comment: @Programmer I created empty project, built it for Android and launched, and rotating worked fine. So problem is in my code :'(

Comment: @Programmer Both scenes. In Android they are transforming into one UnityPlayerActivity, aren't they?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137608/discussion-between-programmer-and-ted-romanus).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While testing I updated `AndroidManifest.xml` file and all started working.

1. Build app without plugin.
2. Get `AndroidManifest.xml` from AndroidStudio project.
3. Update manifest with your activities, services and permissions.
4. Place it in your `Assets/Plugins/Android/` folder.

Answer (score 1):

please check your AndroidManifest.xml
update it

Comment: Refaat, maybe give a little context. Do they need to delete, run update, right click update etc.

Comment: include activities, services, and permissions in AndroidManifest.xml  file, and also apply: clean project and rebuild it, and as well as you have to pass context.